# Translating "さつ... 詐欺だーツ"

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

However I try to translate this, it doesn't make sense.

The context is about a girl that gets annoyed at 2 younger boys and says this.
[image: The context is about a girl that gets annoyed at 2 younger boys and says this.]

Please, I would appreciate if someone could help me by translating and explaining this word by word. Thank you.

Comment: Note that it’s a small ッ not a big ツ at the end.

Comment: And a small っ at the beginning.

Comment: "Fra……",  "It's fraud."

Comment: @JACK What would an attempted translation tell us in this instance? Only that the OP can look up the meaning of 詐欺 in a dictionary. Not all questions need a translation attempt. Admittedly the question could have been better phrased but I don't think adding a translation attempt would serve any useful purpose here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the 「さっ…」 at the beginning of 詐欺{さぎ} (fraud, etc.) is just the speaker stuttering, which combined with the pause after it (…) is used to express disbelief.

The long 「だーーーーッ！」 at the end is just a lengthening of the vowel in the copula 「だ」 much like we would do in English with "Nooooooooo!!!" or "Whaaaaaat?!" to express surprise.